# Add NOT NULL constraint to exsisting column in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have an existing table with columns x, y and z. Trying to set y as PK I get an error that nullable columns cant be set as PK and I couldn't figure out if theres an alternative to creating a new column, copying the data, deleting the original column and renaming the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is nullable, it can not be identified for PK.
Below options will work for you (if the column is having all unique and not-null values).

**Table and data creation:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dev.public.tbl1 (
   x VARCHAR(255),  
   y VARCHAR(255),
   z VARCHAR(255)
);

insert into dev.public.tbl1 (x, y, z) values ('v1', 'v2', 'v3');
insert into dev.public.tbl1 (x, y) values ('v4', 'v5');
```

=======================================================

**Option 1:**
Create a new column with PK, copy values from old column, drop old column, rename new column with desired name.

```
alter table "dev"."public"."tbl1" ADD w VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL default 'A';

UPDATE "dev"."public"."tbl1" SET w=x;

ALTER TABLE "dev"."public"."tbl1" ADD CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (w);

ALTER TABLE "dev"."public"."tbl1" DROP COLUMN x;

ALTER TABLE "dev"."public"."tbl1" RENAME COLUMN w TO x;
```

========================================================

**Option 2:**
Create a similar table with PK in one of the columns and copy table contents from original table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dev.public.tbl2 (
   x VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
   y VARCHAR(255),
   z VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO dev.public.tbl2 SELECT * FROM dev.public.tbl1;
```